# Is this a bug of the classic book Linux Device Drivers?

Tags: c, linux

The following code is excerpted from the classic book *Linux Device Drivers* (3rd Edition, on page 57)

```
static void scull_setup_cdev(struct scull_dev *dev, int index)
{
    int err, devno = MKDEV(scull_major, scull_minor + index);

    cdev_init(&dev->cdev, &scull_fops);
    dev->cdev.owner = THIS_MODULE;
    dev->cdev.ops = &scull_fops;

    err = cdev_add (&dev->cdev, devno, 1);

    /* Fail gracefully if need be */
    if (err)
    printk(KERN_NOTICE "Error %d adding scull%d", err, index);
}
```

What makes me confused is the statement `dev->cdev.ops = &scull_fops;`. Because the preceeding statement `cdev_init(&dev->cdev, &scull_fops);` will do the same thing, that is, `cdev_init()` will execute `dev->cdev.ops = &scull_fops;`, so the following `dev->cdev.ops = &scull_fops;` makes no sense.

Is this a bug of the book?

Comment: That's interesting. Section 3.4.1 of http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-3-sect-4 does the same thing.

Comment: I just checked that `cdev_init` initializes the `ops` field even in kernel 2.6.10, which was the version when LDD3 was written. Also 2.6.9. So you are correct that the statement is redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are correct. They certainly appear to do the same thing to the same data structures. This anomaly is also listed on the book's website in the [Unconfirmed Errata](http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errataunconfirmed.csp?isbn=9780596005900) section. So unless you were the one that submitted that errata suggestion, other people have made the same assumption. The entry is about a quarter of the way down the page. Searching for "scull_fops" will take you right to it.